# Oracle SQL : Grant View only access to a user A for accessing procedure and function definition of other user B

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure, definition, sql-grant

My requirement is to create a user in oracle 11g database and give the following permissions to this user.

1. Select any table (this is fixed and i can do this with Select any table privilege)
2. View definition of all database procedures, functions, packages (unable to do this).
3. I do not want to give execute permission on any procedure or edit permission or delete/drop permission.

Unable to find any relevant help as everywhere it mentions to grant execute or create any procedure which is risky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege (in earlier versions the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` role) gives a user privileges to select from any data dictionary table.

The `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege would give a user privileges to write queries against `DBA_SOURCE` to see the source for any object (or use the `DBMS_METADATA` package), `DBA_VIEWS` to see view definitions, etc.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks, It worked like a charm, but i have not tried yet if this enables the user modify or compile the procedures as well.